# Is any number coprime to itself?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

I have a fundamental question, we know that Coprime numbers are integers that have only 1 as their common factor. Now, my question is how it works for the same numbers, for example, is $10$ coprime to $10$? Since they can be simplified as $\frac{1}{1}$ and $1$ is coprime to $1$.

Comment: If $ a \ne 1 $ then $ a $ has a common factor with itself that is different from 1 (a is a factor of itself).

Comment: $10$ and $10$ have the common factor of $10$ :)

Comment: Only $1$ is coprime to itself.

Comment: The coprime numbers occur only after the simplification.

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation for why $a$ should be coprime to $a$ is the exact reason that $a$ is **not** coprime to $a$ for $a > 1$.

In particular, positive integers $p,q$ are coprime if and only if the fraction $\frac pq$ **cannot** be simplified. The fact that $\frac {10}{10}$ can be simplified to $\frac 11$ means that the numbers $10,10$ are **not** coprime.

---

On the other hand, every positive integer is coprime to $1$. Equivalently, the fractions $\frac 1a$ and $\frac a1$ cannot be simplified.

Comment: It was a misprint writing $1$ as $a$. I meant $1$ is coprime to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Two numbers $a$ and $b$   are coprimes to each other if  $gcd(a,b) =1$. Since $gcd(a,a) = a$ we have $a$ is not coprime with itself for $a \ne 1$.

Comment: It was a misprint writing $1$ as $a$. I meant $1$ is coprime to $1$.